# select() for UDP connection

Tags: c++, sockets, network-programming, udp

Can someone explain to me why we use the `select()` function before `recvfrom()` (on the server side) instead of before `sendto()` (on the client side) when waiting for a timeout? It seems to me that the timeout should be on the sender's side.

```
//EX

CLIENT                              SERVER
------                              ------
select()     /* start timeout */
  sendto()   /* --send packet--> */ recvfrom()
  recvfrom() /*  <--send ACK-- */   sendto()
```

And as long as the ACK has been received before the timeout is reached, the sender could send another file.

Comment: *Why* does it seem so to you? Everybody else uses read timeouts. What's different about your case?

Answer (score 4):

You do not normally use `select` with UDP at all, except you want one of the following:

- receive from several ports (or one port and an unix socket, etc.) with a single thread
- detect other events as soon as they happen, without waiting for an unrelated `recvfrom` or `sendto` to unblock
- sleep in a maximally portable way
- you want to use the Linux-specific `recvmmsg` (but then, you *really* want to use `epoll_wait`) to receive a whole bunch of datagrams with one syscall

`select` is regularly used with TCP as it is able to multiplex between several sockets, one for every connected client. This is not necessary with UDP, since one socket is sufficient to recieve packets from each and every client (assuming they use the same port).

`select` blocks until the condition you wait for (e.g. ready to receive or ready to send) is true. `recvfrom` blocks anyway if there is nothing to receive, so if this is the only thing you're intersted in, calling `select` is useless.

Answer (score 0):

UDP doesn't have built-in acknowledgements. So `sendto()` simply sends the packet to the network and returns immediately, it doesn't have any built-in way of waiting for a response or acknowledgement. Your application knows that it expects the server to send a response, so it waits for a response with `recvfrom()`.